# C - I can't open or read a file generated by a different project

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I am currently trying to create an array and write it to a file "score.dat" in the first project, then read it in a different project.

My first code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int score[20];

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the score for student %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&score[i]);
    }

    FILE * fPtr = fopen("score.dat","wb");

    fwrite(&score, sizeof(score),20,fPtr);

    fclose(fPtr);
}
```

Then, I want to use "score.dat" for the second code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int useroption;
    FILE *fPtr1 = fopen("score.dat","rb");
    FILE *fPtr2 = fopen("score.dat","wb");
    int score[20];

    do
     {
        printf("1. Read and display all data from 'score.dat'.\n2. Multiply all the numbers in 'score.dat' by 2.\n3. Quit.\nEnter your option:");
        scanf("%d", &useroption);

        switch (useroption)
        {
            case 1:
                fread(&score, sizeof(score),20,fPtr1);
                for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
                    printf("%d ", score[i]);
                printf("\n");

            case 2:
                fread(&score,sizeof(int),20,fPtr1);
                for (int j=0;j<20;j++)
                {
                    score[j]*=2;
                }
                fwrite(&score,sizeof(int),20,fPtr2);

            default:
                break;
        }
        while (getchar() != '\n');

    } while (useroption != 3);

    fclose(fPtr1);
    fclose(fPtr2);

    return 0;
}
```

However, while running both these codes, I simply cannot get the values I want from "score.dat". I am out of my depth, much help appreciated.

*I am using CLion

Comment: Can you read it from first project ?

Comment: arent you effectively truncating the file when you open it for writing for fPtr2?

Comment: I think gman nailed it you open "w" that's probably the problem, shd open read+write.

Comment: You are trying to write too much - you are writing your array along with garbage. it should be fwrite(&score, sizeof(score),1,fPtr); And you are reading too much - and it is much more dangerous - it overwrites the stack by your fread call. it should be fread(&score, sizeof(score),1,fPtr1);

Comment: You don't reset the file pointer when you select more than one reading option.

Comment: the first `case 1:` code block falls through to the second `case 2:`  This is probably an error.  Suggest ending the `case 1:` code block with `break;`

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fPtr1 = fopen("score.dat","rb");
    FILE *fPtr2 = fopen("score.dat","wb");`   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful call `perror( "your error message" );` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `fread(&score, sizeof(score),20,fPtr1);`  this will try to read 400 integers.  Perhaps you meant: `fread(&score, sizeof(score),1,fPtr1);`

Comment: if the user enters (for instance `1`) then later enters `1` again -OR- `2` (these entries can be in either order)  this will try to read past the end of the file.  Suggest, just before the `switch()` statement to insert: `rewind( fPtr1 );  rewind( fPtr2 );`  so the file pointers are back at the beginning of the file

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(&score, sizeof(score),20,fPtr);`  This will try to write 400 integers!.  Suggest: `fwrite(&score, sizeof(score),1,fPtr);`  Also, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) from `fread()` and `fwrite()`  if the returned value does not match the third parameter, then some error occurred.

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains the 'magic' number 20.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` or a `enum` to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d",&score[i]);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred